# What is the preferred method of iterating through a string in C?

Tags: c, string, iteration

```
    char *vowels = "aeiouyæøå";
    int len = strlen(vowels);
    int counter;
    for (counter = 0; counter < len; counter++) {
        char vowel = *vowels++;
        printf("%c\n", vowel);
    }
```

Or

```
    char *vowels = "aeiouyæøå";
    int len = strlen(vowels);
    int counter;
    for (counter = 0; counter < len; counter++) {
        char vowel = vowels[counter];
        printf("%c\n", vowel);
    }
```

Or is there a better way?

Comment: The first one doesn't even work right.

Comment: It depends if you need to save the original pointer or not.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII It gives the correct output. What's wrong with it?

Comment: In the first sample you are destroying the initial value of `vowels` (the pointer, not the string itself). What if you need the string after the loop? (Well, yes, you can do `vowels -= len;` but that is just not right)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
char c;
while ( c = *(vowels++) )
{
}
```

No need for `strlen`.

Comment: +1 You may need to enclose the assignment in parenthesis to avoid a compiler warning.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a null-terminated string, that is a character array, that has an additional 0x00 byte at the end, you can use:

```
char *foo = "some string";
char *c = foo;
while(*c)
{
     // ...
     ++c;
}
```

interesting sidefact: 
character strings allocated as constants (e.g. `char *foo = "some string"`) should always be null-terminated.

if you want to sacrifice readability for reduced lines of code count, you can also do the following:

```
char *foo = "some string";
char *c;
for(*c = foo; *c; ++c)
{
     // ...
}
```

Comment: Actually, you can create a character array using a constant that doesn't have a NUL terminator: `char foo[2] = "hi"`.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII good point. however, I'd consider this a byte array rather than a character string.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your second example gives me `warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast` and a segfault.

Comment: @Phoexo you have to be careful what you do with c, because it's a pointer. most likely, you forgot do dereference it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion, but that's hardly better than any of the above. :)

Answer (score 0):

this can be used in functions,I like it because I think it makes it clear that there is, and has to be an '\0' at the end of a string, also there is no traversing the string twice:

```
char some_string[] = "aeiouy";
char *vowels;
for (vowels=some_string ; *vowels != '\0' ; vowels++) {
    char vowel = *vowels;
    printf("%c\n", vowel);
}
```